# How to convert ftp.getModificationTime(file) to readable format

Tags: java, ftp

Hi I need to get the last modified time of the files in an FTP server. I m ve tried two ways but none work:

1) First i tried the getModificationTime() method like this

```
String time = ftp.getModificationTime(filePath);
Date d = new Date(Long.parseLong(time));
```

As a result I receive `time: 20151211120410` and `d: 2608-07-26` , when the correct date is: `2015-11-12`

2) Then I tried the mdtm() method. However, this one returns an `int`. In my case it just returned 213.

Any ideas on how to get the correct modified time and convert it to a readable format?

Thank you

Comment: http://www.codejava.net/java-se/networking/ftp/java-ftp-example-get-and-set-file-modification-time seems to provide exactly what you want

Comment: HI , I ve already checked that link but I get the following exception:
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Date cannot be cast to java.sql.Date

Comment: Make sure you import java.util.Date and not java.sql.Date

Comment: Right that was it , Thnks!!